# API calls are not working in cordova application

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js

I made an application using `apache cordova`. my server is written in `node.js` running locally and port `3005`. So I want to make API call from `cordova` I am using `backbone` in client side.

I written the following code to make API call

```
makingAPICallForStatus:function(){
    var userSessionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({  //Creaating a model for checking user session status
        url:"http://localhost:3005/api/user/status/",
    });
    var userSessionModelObj=new userSessionModel();
    this.makeApiCall(userSessionModelObj,"",'GET',function(model,response,options){console.log(response);});
},
makeApiCall:function(modelObj,dataObject,requestType,successCallback){
    modelObj.fetch({data:dataObject,
            type:requestType,       
            success:successCallback,        
            error:function(){console.log("error")}
    });
}
```

If you observe, I mention URL path is :`"http://localhost:3005/api/user/status/"`. This way it's not working. it's showing `This request has no response data available`

Now I tried with production domain like

URL path is :`"http://xxx.xxxx.com/api/user/status/"`

This way it's working fine.

Why `localhost` was not working, I invoke same url directly in my browser working fine. but it's not working in `cordova`.

Note : I didn't modify anything in `www/config.xml` file.

What's the problem how can I fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: you are running your server on port 3005 but are using the request in port 3004?

Comment: @YoelNunez sorry man, I updated now, can you check it..

Comment: check this post I think it is similar to what you are experiencing [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610020/backbone-js-non-rest-user-model)

Comment: Are you running it in the simulator? If so, use your computer's IP and not `localhost`.

Comment: `localhost` is an alias of `127.0.0.1` even if you are running on an emulator on the same machine, local host is not real. You have to always make calls to an ipaddress or domain name from a device (even virtual devices). This is because on the device `localhost` is referring to the device not the machine that it may be running from.

Comment: @vasan above comment is the answer.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I have a small doubt, what is use of `access` tag in `config.xml` file.

Comment: The access tag is a way of whitelisting urls that the app is allowed to communicate with. most common setting is `*` which is any/all. If you don't include that tag the default behavior should be none.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I did some research on `access` tag, what I understand, whatever domain we mention in `access` tag, our application communicate only with that domain. important this was we can add more `access` tags in our `config.xml` file. Am I right ?

Comment: I have not tried it in any of my apps, but from what I have read yes you can set as many as you need. I have always used the `*` since I didn't need to control what domains my apps are accessing.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is an alias of `127.0.0.1` even if you are running on an emulator on the same machine, local host is not real. You have to always make calls to an ipaddress or domain name from a device (even virtual devices). This is because on the device `localhost` is referring to the device not the machine that it may be running from.